# Building ionic cordova app for Android SDK Platform 30

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic5

Android Play Store requires me to target API level 30 for new releases, but it seems this is not currently supported out of the box.

I try to build the default ionic cordova app:
`ionic start MyApp sidemenu --cordova`
... and select Angular

Then I add the SDK target to confix.xml: `<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="30" />` to config.xml

... remove the whitelist plugin as it is not needed for API level 30: `cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-whitelist`

...and add the android platform: `ionic cordova platform add android@10.1.1`

When I build it: `ionic cordova build android` I get these errors:

```
> Task :CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
C:\Projects\a10\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\com\ionicframework\cordova\webview\IonicWebViewEngine.java:11: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
                                 ^
C:\Projects\a10\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\com\ionicframework\cordova\webview\IonicWebViewEngine.java:137: error: cannot find symbol
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
     ^
  symbol:   class RequiresApi
  location: class com.ionicframework.cordova.webview.IonicWebViewEngine.ServerClient
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
2 errors
```

Here's the repository: https://github.com/geleto/a10
... and this is the ionic info:

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.17.1 (C:\Users\gelet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.8.0
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 12.1.4
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 12.1.4
   @angular/cli                  : 12.1.4
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 4.0.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 10.0.0
   Cordova Platforms : 6.0.0, android 10.1.1, browser
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1, (and 3 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed globally
   native-run  : not installed globally

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Users\gelet\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk)
   NodeJS            : v14.17.5 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 6.14.14
   OS                : Windows 10
```

Comment: Did u make sure u already have sdk 30 installed from android studio (SDK Manager)... your given error is much wide thing especially for android... the affected part in build versions is the plugins u have (plugins may be developed to deal till sdk 29 so they will crash for sdk 30) but overall it should do the build since cordova version 10 supports android sdk 30... so u need to go with details and go with small details... and make sure you have installed androidx plugin and its adapter for sdk 28.+ in case you haven't done that yet since it also affects on +28 sdk builds to fail..

Comment: I have only SDK and build tools for API version  30 installed. When adding the android platform, the target version is listed as 30. The app is freshly generated default ionic application,  no fancy plug-ins here. AndroidX is for legacy Android 8 code, it won't help much here.

Answer (score 2):

Managed to build it by adding `<preference name="AndroidXEnabled" value="true" />` to config.xml and installing cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter

Comment: lol told such things may cause the problem...